# Proving a version of the maximum principle

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

> Suppose $U=\Omega \times (0,\infty),~\Omega$ is a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $u \in C^{2,1}(\overline{U})$ satisfies 
>   $$u_t \leq \Delta u+cu~~\text{in}~U,$$
>   where $c \leq 0$ is a constant.

Question: If $u \geq 0,$ show that the **weak maximum principle** holds for $u.$

I'm still stuck in proving this. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Will someone please be able to provide a proof for this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you examine Evans' proofs in this section, then you'll notice that it's not particularly important that the coefficients $a^{ij}$, $b^i$, and $c$ are continuous. What *is* important to his proofs is that the coefficients are bounded in $U_T$, $T<\infty$. Evans obtains this simply from continuity of the coefficients and compactness of $U_T$, but if you assume the coefficients are *a priori* bounded then this isn't necessary. You should be able to derive your desired result by noting this and proving the weak maximum principle (via exactly Evans' proof) for all $U_T$, $0<T<\infty$.

As for $c\leq 0$ vs $c\geq 0$, note the sign on the second-order coefficients of $L$, versus the coefficients of the Laplacian. Everything should work fine after properly accounting for the change in sign between the hypotheses of each theorem.

Edit: In fact, as Jeff has kindly pointed out to me, the equation in question is constant-coefficient, so Evans' theorem can almost be used without modification. The main modification needed is to deal with the infinite time interval; again, this can be done essentially by proving the weak maximum principle on every $U_T$ for $T$ finite, then letting $T\to\infty$.

Comment: Thank you. I'll check. Could you please give a proof of this.

Comment: Why mention continuity of the coefficients? The OP is considering a constant coefficient equation...

Comment: @Jeff Thank you, I had overlooked this.