# Maximum principle question for heat equation problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, maximum-principle, parabolic-pde

Let $u(t, x) \in C_{t}^{1} C_{x}^{2}\left(\Omega_{T}\right) \cap C(\overline{\Omega_{T}})$ satisfies:

$$
\begin{cases}\partial_{t} u-\Delta u+c(x) u \leq 0, & (t, x) \in \Omega_{T} \\ u(t, x) \leq 0, & (t, x) \in \Gamma_{T}\end{cases}
$$

where $c(x) \geq-c_{0}$ has downside bound, $c_{0}>0$. Prove:

$$
u(t, x) \leq 0, \quad(t, x) \in \Omega_{T}
$$

And I found the usual method used to prove weak maximum principle does not work here ($\partial_t u \ge 0 , \Delta u(t,x)\le 0$ does not make sure $\partial_{t} u-\Delta u+c(x) u \ge 0$).

Besides, I found two answers relative to this question. One is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2068313/proving-a-version-of-the-maximum-principle), but I could not find the proof in Evans' book.

And another is [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2079968/a-proof-for-a-version-of-the-maximum-principle), but obivously that cannot solve when $c$ is not constant.

So can you please give me a hint?

Comment: This cannot be true without further assumptions on either $\Omega$ or $c_0$. Just think of the eigenvalue problem with Dirichlet BCs - it is certainly not true that eigenfunctions must have a sign.

Comment: You must make an assumption that $\Omega$ is ‘small’ in some sense. Usually you assume $\Omega$ is contained within two parallel planes which are close together- try searching maximum principle for narrow domains

Comment: Alternatively you could assume that volume of $\Omega$ to be sufficiently small. This implies the first Dirichlet eigenvalue is large which allows you to recover the maximum principle

Comment: @ JackT Thank you for interest. Is it sufficient that $\Omega$ is bounded and smooth?

Comment: I’ve realised that my above comments are mistaken. They only apply to the elliptic case. Your proof looks completely valid to me. You need $\Omega$ bounded but you don’t need smooth - you can assume a lot less

Comment: It look like this is left as an exercise in Evans. See the remark on page 370 (first edition) or 391 (second).

Comment: @ JackT Ok, I get it. Thanks agian :)

Comment: @ Ali Thank you for advice and I am going to check.

Answer (score 3):

I have figured it out a similar method to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3620027/maximum-principle-for-the-heat-operator).

Let us define $v(t,x):=e^{c_0t}u(t,x)$. Then we have:

$$\begin{aligned}
    &\partial_t v - \Delta v \\
    =& c_0e^{c_0 t}u + e^{c_0 t}\partial_t u - e^{c_0 t}\Delta u \\
    =& e^{c_0 t}(c_0 u + \partial_t u - \Delta u) \le 0 \text{ (by condition) }
\end{aligned}$$

Besides, it's easy to check that $v(t,x)\le 0 , (t,x) \in \Gamma_T$. Thus, by weak maximum principle, $v(t,x)$ cannot be positive in $\Omega_T$, which is same as $u(t,x)$.

:) Wonderful.